# OOP Mysqli connection

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

The `$conn` properties doesn't recognized inside the `function table()` although I run the first function to connect DB

```
include 'connectSQL.php';

$d= new ConnectSQL();
$d->connect();
$d->table();
```

---

```
> class ConnectSQL{

private $host='localhost';
private $Name='root';
private $Pass='';
private $dbName='test';

private $conn;
private $query;
private $results;

public function connect(){

    $conn=mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->Name,$this->Pass,$this->dbName);

    if(!$conn){
        echo 'connection fiald '.mysqli_connect_error();
    }


}


public function table(){


    $this->query="SELECT * FROM tableName";
      $this->results=mysqli_query($this->conn,$this->query);

}



}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with mysql or even  php for that matter. Its a matter of encapsulation and understanding how private variable work. In most C based programming languages instance properties need to be accessed/mutated with a keyword `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `table` method refers to `$this->conn`, but the connect method does not set `$this->conn`.

In this line of code:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->Name,$this->Pass,$this->dbName);
```

The `$conn` variable only exists in the scope of the `connect` method. You'll need to use `$this->conn` instead to assign the connection to the private property.